# Do graphic design questions for iPhone apps belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope, site-recommendation

I'm tempted to start asking a whole bunch of questions about how to design various background, buttons, promotional screenshots, and icons for iPhone apps.

For example **if I want to imitate various backgrounds, icon designs, or promotional screenshots made by Arawella Corporation, is Stack Overflow a good place to post such questions**, or is there a more appropriate place to do so?

I'm not sure if such questions belong on Stack Overflow under the [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) tag.

Will anyone care to comment/clarify?

Comment: Depends. Are you going to be using a programming language or, say, Photoshop?

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't think these questions belong on Stack Overflow.

They don't fit into any of the categories listed in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Graphic design questions have nothing to do with programming or software algorithms, and graphic design-related software packages like Photoshop don't even fall into the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers". The fact that you're designing these graphics for an iPhone application is merely a coincidence; you could be designing the same graphics for all sorts of promotional materials completely unrelated to programming.

Additionally, not only are those graphic design questions, but they also sound like *legal* questions; i.e., whether you can imitate materials distributed by Arawella Corporation. Questions of that nature are not on topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, as we don't currently have a legal Q&A site.

For those that aren't legal/usage-related questions, but rather specific, answerable questions about creating graphics, you might consider posting them to the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) site.
Do have a look at their FAQ first to see which types of questions are on topic:

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward 2D design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - Digital media
>   Examples: video, Adobe Flash
>
> but not about:
>
> - Simple "How to" questions
> - Brainstorming or idea gathering
> - Technical questions related to 3D software
> - Technical questions related to video editing software
> - Web site architecture and development
>   Examples: HTML that doesn't include CSS, server-side issues
> - Landscaping and architecture

Comment: The UX (user experience) stack exchange site would be another good place to go, as UX and graphic design often go hand and hand.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I haven't seen User Experience SE, I'll check there.